# Icon not displaying when exe is created in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

For the exe generated, the Icon is not displayed. I added the Icon in the project Properties --> Make tab --> Application --> Icon.  I am using Vb 6.0
I can see the icon in the project properties. but the same is not displayed when the exe is generated.

I added the icon in the resource file too. But   its not displayed.
I added the image for it.

Any ideas on displaying the icon for the exe generated?

Comment: Where exactly are you expecting the icon to be displayed? Windows Explorer view of the exe? Can you post a screenshot of the missing icon?

Comment: Yes ... its in windows explorer view of exe.. sorry I tried posting the screenshot. but its not uploading.. its like if My Computer on the desktop has monitor icon.. the exe generated wil not hav any icon..just a blank is seen.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

We've had problems with that in the past.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with your icon dimensions being out of scope.  Hack workaround - add a dummy form  (frmIconHolder) with the 32x32 icon you want as the icon for that form.  Then in the project Properties --> Make tab --> Application --> Icon, set it to this new form.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to setting your exe's icon:

1:  Set your Main Form's icon to the icon you want to use for the exe.  On the make tab, from the Application Icon drop-down, select your form that has the icon you want to use.  Compile.

2:  Using a resource file.  To do this, check out [this forum post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=432036).  Using this method, you have to use icons with max 256 colors.

Comment: Hi. I tried many methods for this. But I can only see the blank ICON on the desktop(or any other loc..).

Answer (score 0):

The empirically-found boundaries for VB6 icons are: ICO format on ly, 48x48 in size, 16/24-bit colours

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your Icon does not exceed 256 colors and it has both 16x16 and 32x32 images in it.